# Django Annotate ExpressionWrapper Does not Return Expected Type

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-mysql

I have the following models:

```
class Creditor(models.Model):
    terms_of_payment = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

class Invoice(models.Model):
    creditor = models.ForeignKey(
        Creditor,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    reception_date = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

I am getting type `int` for **due_on** from the following queryset, instead of `datetime.date` and can't figure out why.

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.annotate(
    due_on=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('reception_date') + F('creditor__terms_of_payment'),
        output_field=DateField()
    )
)
```

The database I'm using is MySQL.
So basically if `reception_date=datetime.date(2021, 5, 13)` and `terms_of_payment=2`, I expect to get `datetime.date(2021, 5, 15)` but I'm getting `2021515` which is `<class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was `terms_of_payment` was an `IntegerField` instead of `DurationField`. In order for this queryset to yield a `datetime`, always a DurationField should be added to a DateTimeField. These corresponds to `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedela` in Python.

```
class Creditor(models.Model):

    terms_of_payment = models.DurationField(
        default=datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    )
```